# SQL trying to get savings %

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to get the savings % but it keeps giving me the column as NULL or giving me an error. I have the Retail (RetOne) which is lower price I then have Ret2 which is one version of the Higher retail (EOB retail) and the other version of the retail (ORIGINALRETAIL). The problem comes in wen either EOB retail or Originalretail are blank so I attempted to 0 them out when Null. When I do that I get an error. if I remove that statement it just Nulls the whole savings %. Ive isolated the part of the code giving me the issue. ",Round...."
Any help or step in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
 SELECT CatID + ' ' + Cast(Year(GETDATE()) as Varchar) AS [PRF/YR]
,dbo.Lago_CID_Master.ARTICLE AS PACK
,'' AS [$ Per Month]
,CASE When ORIGINALRETAIL >.01 THEN Round(ORIGINALRETAIL-RetOne,2)
When Ret2 >.01 THEN Round(Ret2-RetOne,0) END AS [Buy Multi]
,CASE When ORIGINALRETAIL >.01 Then ORIGINALRETAIL
When ORIGINALRETAIL <.01 Then NULL End AS [Sale Higher Retail]
,CASE When Ret2 >.01 THEN [Ret2]
When Ret2 <.01 THEN null End AS [EOB Retail]
,dbo.PIC704Current.HeavyWeightCode AS [HvyWt Code]
,'' AS [Addtl Ship]
,'' AS [Compare To]


,Round(Case when ret2 is Null or ret2=0 or originalretail is null or 
originalretail=0 then Null else (isnull(Ret2,0)+isnull(ORIGINALRETAIL,0)- 
RetOne)/isnull(Ret2,0) end ,0) AS [% Savings]


,'' AS [Blank]
,dbo.PIC704Current.RetOne AS Retail
,CASE When [HvyWgtDollars]=9 Then 9.95
When [HvyWgtDollars]>1 THEN [HvyWgtDollars]
When [HvyWgtDollars]<1 THEN null end AS [Size Charge]
,'' AS [Blank1]
,'' AS [Postage]
,'' AS [Total]
,dbo.PIC704Current.PostPaidFlag AS [Post Paid]
,dbo.Lago_CID_Master.WPFROM AS [Page]
,'' AS [MBRSHP Retail]
,'' AS [Special Credit]
,dbo.PIC704Current.WeightComment AS [Food Weight]
,dbo.PIC704Current.CatOrdPolicy AS [News]
,dbo.PIC704Current.DiscountReasonCode AS [Disc Reason]
,dbo.PIC704Current.Description AS [Description]
,'' AS [T/T Notes]
,'' AS [Truck Ship]
,'' AS Uniques, dbo.Lago_CID_Master.SPREADNAME AS [Spreadnames]
,dbo.PIC704Current.Excl AS [Exclusives]
FROM dbo.PIC704Current INNER JOIN dbo.Lago_CID_Master ON 
dbo.PIC704Current.PackNum = dbo.Lago_CID_Master.ARTICLE
WHERE dbo.PIC704Current.CatID Like 'LW'
ORDER BY dbo.Lago_CID_Master.WPFROM, dbo.PIC704Current.DiscountReasonCode 
DESC;
```

Comment: Know your RDBMS. SQL Server <> MySQL.

Comment: @Larnu - yeah but he's talking about _his_ sql....  Doesn't that count? #mySql

Comment: I'll be here all weekend - thanks folks

Comment: You have `then Null else` for the `AS [% Savings]` field, shouldn't that be **`then 0 else`**?

Comment: If any of your retail prices are NULL I recommend replacing them with the known price, not 0, otherwise calculating your saving might be infinite percent

Comment: What happens if you move the null/0 test outside of the round function?

Comment: @AbeMiessler #MySQL <> MySQL? :D

Comment: They're the same, except the former is more forgetful because of all the hash

Comment: try NULLIF . http://www.peachpit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=Avoiding-division-by-zero-with-NULLIF-Five-SQL-Tips-in-Five-Days-Part-5- .. it will fix your issue if ur in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this expression:

```
isnull(Ret2,0)+isnull(ORIGINALRETAIL,0)- RetOne)/isnull(Ret2,0)
```

Particularly, the right side of the division operation:

```
isnull(Ret2,0)
```

Pop quiz: what happens when you divide by zero?

The `case` expression already checks whether `Ret2` is null and would ensure the correct result for the entire calculation as whole, but Sql Server still wants to evaluate that partial expression, and you can't divide by zero. But since you do have that `case` to fall back on, just use something other than 0 as the default value, so the expression survives long enough to finish evaluating the CASE.

I would also tend to build this so the `NULL` is the fallback for the `ELSE` condition:

```
Round(CASE WHEN coalesce(ret2,0) <> 0 and coalesce(originalretail,0) <> 0 
          THEN (isnull(Ret2,0)+isnull(ORIGINALRETAIL,0)- RetOne)/isnull(Ret2,1)  
          ELSE NULL END,0) AS [% Savings]
```

Comment: The reason I am adding Null is because this query goes directly into an upload file that can't have 0's in the Ret2 or originalretail columns so I was trying to keep them blank. Hope that helps explain the whole reason I am using Null

Comment: division by zero is botch you up main man. NULLIF(Ret2,0) will fix your issue.

Comment: yeah I get that. I'm new to SQL programming so I don't know all the functions or statements and this one is a bit more complicated. If we didn't have two different columns that have higher retails this wouldn't be as complicated. Otherwise a simple Higher retail - Retail / Higher Retail = % but because there are two fields and there is the added later that there are blank cells or = 0 it throws everything into confusion. Thanks for the help you've pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE WHEN ...` for `AS [% Savings]` returns `NULL` where it should return 0. The fix:

```
ROUND(
    CASE WHEN ret2 IS NULL OR ret2 = 0
           OR originalretail IS NULL OR originalretail = 0
         THEN 0      -- FIX: 0 instead of NULL
         ELSE ...
    END), 0) AS [% Savings]
```

*Furthermore*, the `ELSE` tries to handle `NULL` values while actually all `NULLs` and even zeroes are leading to the `THEN` part being processed. Assuming that is what you want, the `ELSE` can then be simplified, leading to this:

```
ROUND(
    CASE WHEN ret2 IS NULL OR ret2 = 0
           OR originalretail IS NULL OR originalretail = 0
         THEN 0
         ELSE (Ret2 + ORIGINALRETAIL - RetOne) / Ret2
    END), 0) AS [% Savings]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that fixed it

```
 (Round(case when ret2 <> 0 or originalretail <> 0 
  then case when ret2 > 0 then (ret2- retone)/ret2 
  when originalretail > 0 then (originalretail-retone)/originalretail 
  else null end end,2))*100 as [Savings %]
```